# populate the results of my Fiscal Year calculator into and empty column in existing table

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I ran this command at the beginning of my script:

```
declare @date dataetime = getdate();
SELECT (YAR(DATEADD(Month,-((DATEPART(Month,@date)+11) %12),@date))) AS FiscalYear

SELECT DateofIngest, ContractYear, FiscalYear from [database].[dbo].[TableNameA] 
....(many other commands that are working)
into [Table.NameB]
```

The FiscalYear calculation works and gives results as a separate query than the second SELECT statement. how do I make the results from the first Select (establishing FiscalYear) into the FiscalYear column of existing permanent table? Thanks.

Comment: With an update maybe? It is hard to tell what you are asking here.

Comment: Hi Sean. I imported an excel file that has a FiscalYear column (with no values yet) and in SQL server I wanted to create a value for fiscal year and have that column populate with that field. I imported the data using SSIS but did not perform any transforms on import. Instead, I am running after import with various transforms on various columns. How do I get the calculation of FiscalYear to populate the existing table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does it? I'm not familiar with `YAR` and `dataetime`. I understand those are typo's though.

You can add the parameter to your query....

```
SELECT @date, DateofIngest, ContractYear, FiscalYear from [database].[dbo].[TableNameA] 
....(many other commands that are working)
into [Table.NameB]
```

Or, if you have a datetime column, use that in place of @date....

```
SELECT DateofIngest, ContractYear, YEAR(DATEADD(Month,-((DATEPART(Month,DateColumn)+11) %12),DateColumn))from [database].[dbo].[TableNameA] 
....(many other commands that are working)
into [Table.NameB]
```

Comment: Yes, they were typos.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here. But it sounds like you have already imported this data to some table? Assuming that is correct and you can identify the rows you need to correct because currently the FiscalYear column is null you can do this easily with an update statement.

```
Update SomeTable
set FiscalYear = datepart(year, DATEADD(Month,-((DATEPART(Month,getdate())+11) %12),getdate()))
Where FiscalYear IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean. I did this, but when I do a SELECT FiscalYear afterward, the results are still NULL.

Comment: Huh? How can an update using a scalar value be NULL? Is this done on the sql server side after you import the data? We are really shooting blind here. If you could post some table definitions and sample data this would be a lot easier.